# Could someone give more examples where "We all are" is suitable, since "We are all" is the default option?

Tags: word-usage

This [post](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/128852/373332) gives nice explanation about "We are all" vs. "We all are":

> Both are grammatical, but the first is more usual. We are all is much more frequent than we all are in both the Corpus of Contemporary American English and in the British National Corpus. There are, however, some contexts where we all are would be used.

and gives this easy to understand example.

> The answer to the question Who is responsible? might be We all are, and not We are all.

Could someone give more examples where "We all are" is suitable, since "We are all" is the default option?

Comment: In the example, _we all_ is used because the word _responsible_ is not repeated in the answer. ('We are _all_ responsible' is a possible answer, but not 'We are all'.)

Comment: I've never given this a moment of thought before now.  I have a tendency to *contract*, so I would probably say *we're all* since you cannot contract if the *we are* if there is an *all* in the middle.  They are fully interchangeable.  Who is responsible? *We're all responsible.*

Answer (score 0):

Well .. The difference is on emphasis

> **We all are** emphasizes on : *Who ? Us* or otherwise: **all of us** E.g *We all are hungry*
>
> **We are all** emphasizes on : We're Totally Sth E.g : *We are all tired*

But i use the second one for both of the situtations because it's more **common**